# Products are not displayed in magento homepage?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I added some products in the magento admin panel, but i don't know how to display that to my homepage..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in home page

{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="166" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"}}

OR

Create new singleproduct.phtml file in your template directory
visit

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19173/

for more detail